# discord.js v13 How do I verify a guildMember is also a member of another guild?

Tags: discord.js

This is my first post here, sorry in advance if the formatting isn't great.

I'll try to keep it short and sweet. I've made a small bot with discord.js v13 and it's main purpose is to check if new people that join is part of another guild, if they are they get a role and if they had a nickname, they'll get that assigned. The bot is on both servers with full admin rights and the server members intent is enabled. I've tried all sorts of things.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
const {other_server_ID, role_ID, text_channel_ID} = require("../config.json");
module.exports = {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd',
    async execute( member, bot ) {
        //Log the newly joined member to console
        console.log(member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!');

        if(member.bot) return

        const text_channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(text_channel_ID)
        const role = member.guild.roles.cache.get(role_ID)
        text_channel.send(member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!')
        const other_server = bot.guilds.cache.get(other_server_ID)

        const other_server_member = other_server.members.cache.get(member.user.id)

        console.log(other_server_member)

        if (other_server_member === null) text_channel.send(member.user.tag + " was not a member of other_server :(")
        else {
            text_channel.send(member.user.tag + " was a member of other_server!")

            if(!other_server_member.nickname){
                text_channel.send(member.tag + " had no nickname on other_server.")
            }
            else {
                await member.setNickname(other_server_member.nickname)
                text_channel.send("Their old nickname, " + other_server_member.nickname + ", was returned to them! :)")
            }
            if(!member.guild.roles.cache.get(role_ID)){
                text_channel.send("Role not found.")}
            else{
                await member.roles.add(role)
                text_channel.send("They were given the role " + role.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the other server (it works that far) and then try to grab the user from the other server's cache. Currently I try with get and the user.id but I have also tried:

```
const other_server_member = other_server.members.cache.find(mem => mem.user.id === member.user.id) || other_server.members.cache.find(mem => mem.user.tag === member.user.tag) || null
```

I found that code snippet during my search for a solution. So far I always got errors because other_server_member was always undefined/null. I also tried putting await infront of the find/get part.

Thanks for your help and time.

UPDATE:

It works fine with fetch(), code now looks like this:

```
    const {other_server_ID, role_ID, text_channel_ID} = require("../config.json");
module.exports = {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd',
    async execute( member, bot ) {
        //Log the newly joined member to console
        console.log(member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!');

        if(member.bot) return

        const text_channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(text_channel_ID)
        const role = member.guild.roles.cache.get(role_ID)
        text_channel.send(member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!')
        const other_server = bot.guilds.cache.get(other_server_ID)

        const other_server_member = null
        try {
            other_server_member = await other_server.members.fetch(member.user.id)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            return text_channel.send(member.user.tag + " was not a member of " + pluto.name + ".")
        }

        console.log(other_server_member)

        if (other_server_member === null) text_channel.send(member.user.tag + " was not a member of other_server :(")
        else {
            text_channel.send(member.user.tag + " was a member of other_server!")

            if(!other_server_member.nickname){
                text_channel.send(member.tag + " had no nickname on other_server.")
            }
            else {
                await member.setNickname(other_server_member.nickname)
                text_channel.send("Their old nickname, " + other_server_member.nickname + ", was returned to them! :)")
            }
            if(!member.guild.roles.cache.get(role_ID)){
                text_channel.send("Role not found.")}
            else{
                await member.roles.add(role)
                text_channel.send("They were given the role " + role.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your discord.js version?

Comment: @Crytek1012 v13. I added it to the Question.

Comment: Can you try using `fetch` instead? `const other_server_member = other_server.members.fetch(member.user.id)`

Comment: @Crytek1012 Thanks, if finally works :D
I have no clue what the problem with get is, it would constantly throw errors and break other stuff.